# Fortran 2003, Passing Derived Type to an Argument of Parent Type

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, fortran, derived-class

After searching, I was able to find one question regarding the same error I just encountered, but for different reasons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502592/procedure-pointer-derived-type) (they weren't familiar with `pass`... different issue).

My question is simple. In Fortran, can a function expecting an argument of type `class(parent)` accept instead `class(derived_from_parent)`?

If an example or clarification is needed, please ask. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that works without any problem. If you need to use any property of the extended (derived) type, you have to use `select type`, but if not, it is without any complication.

If you need the dummy argument to be `allocatable` or `pointer`, there are some restrictions:

> 12.5.2.5
>
> 2 The actual argument shall be polymorphic if and only if the associated
> dummy argument is polymorphic, and either both the actual and dummy
> arguments shall be unlimited polymorphic, or the declared type of the
> actual argument shall be the same as the declared type of the dummy
> argument.

(the reason for this is explained in NOTE 12.27 in ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010)

Comment: Worth noting exceptions exist for dummy arguments with the allocatable or pointer attribute.

Comment: @VladimirF @IanH So is the appropriate syntax that the passed argument is first declared as `class(derived_from_parent), allocatable` or `class(derived_from_parent), pointer` but the dummy argument must be of form `class(parent)`, leaving off `, allocatable` or `, pointer`? Have I interpreted your comments correctly? With that syntax the procedure will correctly accept the derived type?

Comment: If you do it that way everything is OK, IanH was referring to a more advanced case where you need the dummy to be allocatable or pointer for some reason. In that case the declared types have to match.